# Inertia JS consume laravel api

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-router, inertiajs

I know that inertia does not need to vue router but I have a Laravel API that I will consume from a vue app and react native app (mobile), the web side (vue app), I install it inside the laravel project, with Inertia. Now I want consume Laravel routes with json responses I don't want to render an Inertia object, But the `Link` component receive an inertia responce like this in backEnd : 
 `return Inertia::render('...')`   
 when I return an apiResponse : I got this error:
`All Inertia requests must receive a valid Inertia response, however a plain JSON response was received.`

I know this is not an error but there is a way to work with Inertia on front-end and API resource on back-end ? Or Can I use vue-router instead of inertia router ?

my objective is let the back-end generic to all type of front-end application. so I must return json response.

Comment: why not create a separate routes for mobile ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use Inertia shared data concept to achieve what you're trying to do. You can have a helper method which accepts your intended JSON response as argument
Something like:

```
function customResponse($response)
{
        if (request()->inertia()){
            return redirect()->back()->with('response_data', $response);
        } else {
            return response()->json($response);
        }
}
```

Change your `App\Http\Middleware\HandleInertiaRequests` middleware to have a data key in Shared data

```
public function share(Request $request): array
{
    return array_merge(parent::share($request), [
        ...
        'response_data' => fn () => $request->session()->get('response_data')
        ],
    ]);
}
```

Now, just call `customResponse` function with the payload and you'll be getting JSON response for your API and Inertia response for Inertia calls. You can access that data in Inertia like this:

```
form.post(route('some-route'), {
    onSuccess: (response) => {
        console.log(response.props.response_data);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to return JSON resources, use [Axios](https://axios-http.com/docs/intro).

[InertiaJS](https://inertiajs.com/) is used to build single-page apps, without building an API.

That said, Inertia is not used to build APIs. When you do requests to Inertia, it's response is an Inertia response and can't be another type of response than that one. Click [here](https://inertiajs.com/how-it-works) to know how it works.